# loading Ace causes Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, ace-editor

I am trying to use [ace text editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). Ace library `ace.js` seems to require a library `require.js`, and I have html code that initially looks like this (with some elements omitted):

```
<html><body>
  <script src="path/to/require.js">
  <script src="path/to/ace.js">
<body></html>
```

At some timing after document load, an ajax call inserts a target `<div>` to be turned into a text editor, and a `<script>` node into the dom, resulting in a structure like this:

```
<html><body>
  <div id="foo">Hello World</div>
  <script>ace.edit('foo');</script>
  <script src="path/to/require.js">
  <script src="path/to/ace.js">
<body></html>
```

The ajax functions work only after the document is loaded, so it is certain that by the time the part `<script>ace.edit('foo');</script>` is added to the dom, the files `require.js` and `ace.js` have been loaded.

When ajax is done, JavaScript raises this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, module) {
"use strict";

require("./lib/fixoldbrowsers");

var dom = require("./lib/dom");
var event = require("./lib/event");

var Editor = require("./editor").Edito...<omitted>...ch
```

which comes from `require.js`. I looks like this error is common for `require.js`, and I can see a description [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch), which says:

> If you manually code a script tag in HTML to load a script with an anonymous define() call, this error can occur.

but I have no idea what that means. I believe `ace.js` is calling `require`, but `ace.js` is not directly coded in a `<script>` tag, it is in a file, called through `<script src="...">`.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [pre-packaged ace.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/), then you do not need require.js, `ace` will use it's own `define`. If you include both `require.js` and `ace.js` then you need to use the `src-noconflict` version.

If you are using `require.js`, then you should use it to load ace, rather than using the `src` attribute of a `<script>` tag (this is what your error description is talking about):

```
<script>
  var ace = require("./path/to/ace");
</script>
```

Do not include the `.js` extension on that path.